# how to develop navigation view inside sub navigation view with multiple selection in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, submenu

I am new in Android. I am developing one app in android, Minimum API level is 15 and Maximum API level is 23.

I want [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjt0A.png), and another thing is multiple selection item in sub navigation. When any item is selected from parent navigation view, child navigation view will be open, as shown in image. I search on google but not getting answer. I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042958/android-adding-a-submenu-to-a-menuitem-where-is-addsubmenu) and other so many stack overflow answer but not getting. please if some one help then it's very appreciate.Thanks in advance.

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my javafile

```
public class HomePageActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    ListView lvList;

    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    NavigationViewAdapter adapter;

    ArrayList<RowObject> selectedItemArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hope_page);

        lvList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvList);

        setUpListView();

        lvList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        lvList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedItemArray.size(); i++)
            {
                if (i == position){
                    selectedItemArray.get(position).setSelectedItem(true);
                }else{
                    selectedItemArray.get(i).setSelectedItem(false);
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    }

    private void setUpListView()
    {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        selectedItemArray = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            arrayList.add("Item "+(i+1));
            selectedItemArray.add(new RowObject(i, false));
        }
        adapter = new NavigationViewAdapter(HomePageActivity.this, arrayList, selectedItemArray);
        if (adapter != null)
        {
            lvList.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my adapter

```
public class NavigationViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Activity activity;

    View itemView;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;

    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    ArrayList<RowObject> selectedItemArray;

    public NavigationViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> arrayList, ArrayList<RowObject> selectedItemArray)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.selectedItemArray = selectedItemArray;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        try
        {
            itemView = convertView;
            if (convertView == null){
                itemView = inflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_activity_item, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                //if this is first time then inflate view
                viewHolder.itemName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
                itemView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder)itemView.getTag();
            }

            //set Data from ArrayList
            viewHolder.itemName.setText(arrayList.get(position));

            if (selectedItemArray.get(position).isSelectedItem()){
                viewHolder.itemName.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            }else{
                viewHolder.itemName.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();

            return itemView;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView itemName;
    }
}
```

this is my RowObject.java

```
public class RowObject
{
    public int position;
    boolean isSelectedItem;

    public RowObject(int position, boolean isSelectedItem) {
        this.position = position;
        this.isSelectedItem = isSelectedItem;
    }
    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
    public boolean isSelectedItem() {
        return isSelectedItem;
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(boolean isSelectedItem) {
        this.isSelectedItem = isSelectedItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: You like this?
Please look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929386/actionbar-menu-items-in-master-detail-flow)

Comment: what will you tried ?

Comment: Shailesh Limbadiya i am able to generate list but i have no idea about how to add and show sub navigation view?

Comment: please share your xml and java file.

Comment: please share your RowObject class code

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this type of layout is not provided by android but you can fixed  using your logic. I think you need to change your xml file, because your listview width is `match_parent` so your whole screen filled and your second sub menu is not display.Please change that or fix as per your requirement. Your main xml file.

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvList"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lvList"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lvList">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llItemContainer"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/input_login_hint">

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And add one method in your listview onItemClickListener(). Please see my code.
**java file**.

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ListView lvList;
    LinearLayout llItemContainer;

    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    NavigationViewAdapter adapter;

    ArrayList<RowObject> selectedItemArray;
    ArrayList<String> selectedSecondItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_activity);

        lvList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvList);

        setUpListView();

        lvList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        llItemContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llItemContainer);
        lvList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                for (int i = 0; i < selectedItemArray.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (i == position){
                        selectedItemArray.get(position).setSelectedItem(true);
                    }else{
                        selectedItemArray.get(i).setSelectedItem(false);
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //here you can pass your sub view item array
                generateSubView(position);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpListView()
    {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        selectedItemArray = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            arrayList.add("Item "+(i+1));
            selectedItemArray.add(new RowObject(i, false));
        }
        adapter = new NavigationViewAdapter(NavigationActivity.this, arrayList, selectedItemArray);
        if (adapter != null)
        {
            lvList.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private void generateSubView(int position)
    {
        try
        {
            selectedSecondItem = new ArrayList<>();
            llItemContainer.removeAllViews();

            for (int i = 0; i <= position; i++)
            {
                final TextView rowText = new TextView(NavigationActivity.this);
                TableRow.LayoutParams paramsExample = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        147,2.0f);
                rowText.setId(i);
                rowText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                rowText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                rowText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                paramsExample.setMargins(3, 3, 3, 3);
                rowText.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
                rowText.setTextSize(18);
                rowText.setText("SecondItem " + i);
                rowText.setLayoutParams(paramsExample);

                rowText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        rowText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

                        selectedSecondItem.add(rowText.getText().toString());
                    }
                });

                llItemContainer.addView(rowText);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

you get the selected item from sub navigation view  in `selectedSecondItem` arraylist.

Comment: Thanks. Its work charm.I try last five day.you save my time.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio > New > Activity > Master/Detail Flow

Google docs [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929386/actionbar-menu-items-in-master-detail-flow)

OR

Stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929386/actionbar-menu-items-in-master-detail-flow)

Comment: thanks for your response. It is not exactly what i want but it's near by, i will check this and try if i achieve. thanks